# SQL timestamp per column

Tags: sql

Typically tables have a column called `LastModifiedDate/Updated` date. We were wondering how to implement a more advanced variation of this. We require a timestamp whenever any column value changes.

We can manually make this change by adding N timestamp columns representing current existing columns. For example `Contact.FirstName` would also now have `Contact.FirstNameLastModifiedDate`.

Unfortunately this change is drastic. We were wondering if there's a possibly better approach.

Comment: If you're inserting new rows vs updating existing ones, you only need the one create date. You can then compare to previous rows to see what was changed.

Comment: Not sure how this would work. I need all information at once. If the row has been edited 15 times. Each iteration edited a new column. How do you get that data. Second is, how do you even get previous rows then?

Comment: Have a separate log table. Store before row and after row, and timestamp. Use triggers for this.

Comment: Example: Person moves so you need to input a new address. Create a new row with all of the existing person data (id, name, age, etc...) but with the new address and createDate. The old address is still in the database but with an old create date. You can compare the two based on the date (max(createDate) is active). You could also add an end date to the table so make it easier to see which is active. Update the 'old' rows with an end date so the only row without one is the latest. You can then select where endDate is null to get the active row.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. The log/audit table approach is probably correct but there may be specific capabilities built into your DBMS

Comment: A general approach for this task is a log table with exactly the same structure (or `old_columnname, new_columnname` per column), which is insert-only and is filled within a trigger with previous values of changed rows (updated or deleted).

Comment: One example is https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/

Comment: Add a trigger to the `UPDATE` operations.

Comment: Perhaps you should use [Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16). They store the entire history of changes, from which you can extract all the dates of changes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically no RDBMS manages this automatically, it's down to you to implement the specific solution you need.

I actually have this implemented two different ways in various database solutions, which might give you some ideas.

My implementations are in SQL Server / Azure but in principle can apply anywhere.

I have numerous tables where I audit and track modified date/time data for specific columns. This is accomplished by an update trigger on the table; it captures some database-platform specific information such as the table name, column name(s), application name, login, process-Id etc and logs to an audit table. Several tables log to the same audit table where additional reports/queries can pull information for a specific table.

For other tables I have implemented [system-versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) which is something that many platforms support natively.

This creates what is known as a *temporal table* where the database engine automatically logs change history and also provides some sql-language extensions to query the historical data.

Using systsem-versioning you can retrieve the data as it was at any point in time, know when it changed etc for any column in a system-versioned table.